React dnd-kit sortable by order_id rather than index?
The code is based on array and sort the items bae on index, is it possible to do so on array of objects and based on "order_id" inside each and one of the objects?
      setItems((items) => {
        const oldIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
        const newIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
        
        return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
      });

i.e
change data structure from array of numbers to sort base on object that has order_id, e.g:
[
{order_id: 2},
{order_id: 3},
{order_id: 1}
]



Not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you talking about the initial order of items? İf that is the case, can't you sort the array before passing it to the desired place?
